# GLSurfaceView.Renderer is not working with android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, glsurfaceview

I have strange issue. When I try to add

> new GLSurfaceView.Renderer()

to my activity because I want to get info for renderer with

> glGetString(GL10.GL_RENDERER)

it is not working. If I hide the ViewPager view it is showing the info. Any ideas how to fix this? I tried switching visibility on viewpager to visible after creating glsurface but it is not working again. It works only with viewpager view invisible which is not an option. Here is part of my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
    private LinearLayout rlRoot;
    GLSurfaceView.Renderer mGLRenderer;

    private void setupGL() {
        mGLRenderer = new GLSurfaceView.Renderer() {
            public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
            }

            public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int i, int i2) {
            }

            public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eGLConfig) {
                if (gl10 != null) {
                    gl10.glClearColor(8.0f, 8.0f, 8.0f, 0.0f);

                    Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated: " + gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_RENDERER));

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (MainActivity.this.mGLSurfaceView != null) {
                                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) MainActivity.this.mGLSurfaceView.getParent();
                                if (viewGroup != null) {
                                    viewGroup.removeView(MainActivity.this.mGLSurfaceView);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Paper.init(this);

        setupGL();
        rlRoot = findViewById(R.id.linear);
        mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(MainActivity.this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mGLRenderer);
        rlRoot.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
        detectOpenGLESGPUInfo();

        init();
    }

    private void detectOpenGLESGPUInfo() {

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        if (viewGroup != null) {
            this.mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
            this.mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        String language = Paper.book().read("language");

        if (language == null) {
            Paper.book().write("language", "en");
            language = "en";
        }

        Context context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, language);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();


        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentCPU(), resources.getString(R.string.cpu));
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentCamera(), resources.getString(R.string.camera_fragment));
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentBattery(), resources.getString(R.string.battery));
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentDisplay(), resources.getString(R.string.display));
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentSensors(), resources.getString(R.string.sensors));
        Log.d(TAG, "init: " + adapter);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried the layout inspector to verify that the view has enough size in order to be visible?

Comment: I don't need GLSurface View to be visible, I just need the info                     Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated: " + gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_RENDERER));

Comment: You may be able to do it without layouts ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837652/how-to-detect-opengl-capabilities-without-creating-a-glsurfaceview-android but anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with adding another layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```